# Replace multi-spacing in strings with single whitespace - Python

Tags: python, string, whitespace, replace, removing-whitespace

The overhead in looping through the string and replacing double spaces with single ones is taking too much time. Is a faster way of trying to replace multi spacing in strings with a single whitespace?

I've been doing it like this, but it's just way too long and wasteful:

```
str1 = "This is    a  foo bar   sentence with  crazy spaces that  irritates   my program "

def despace(sentence):
  while "  " in sentence:
    sentence = sentence.replace("  "," ")
  return sentence

print despace(str1)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

look at this

```
In [1]: str1 = "This is    a  foo bar   sentence with  crazy spaces that  irritates   my program "

In [2]: ' '.join(str1.split())
Out[2]: 'This is a foo bar sentence with crazy spaces that irritates my program'
```

The method `split()` returns a list of all the words in the string, using str as the separator (splits on all whitespace if left unspecified)

Answer (score 5):

Using [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re
str1 = re.sub(' +', ' ', str1)
```

`' +'` matches one or more space characters.

You can also replace all runs of whitespace with

```
str1 = re.sub('\s+', ' ', str1)
```