# Optimizing pandas operation: combining first/middle/last name columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

Let's say I take a sample of names such as these separated by individual fields:

```
indx  First Name   Middle Name     Last Name
0     CHARITIXAN   K.R.,           NICHOLS
1           None   Johnny-Boy      CHAVEZ
2          ISAAC   None            ESPARZA
3        MICHAEL   nan             
4         Andrew                   Pfaff
```

Let's also assume these data are formatted as a pandas dataframe (df) and 
enough cleaning (via the `.replace` method) has been done to where all
values that remain are only occupied strings or empty strings.

```
indx  First Name   Middle Name     Last Name
0     CHARITIXAN   K.R.,           NICHOLS
1                  Johnny-Boy      CHAVEZ
2          ISAAC                   ESPARZA
3        MICHAEL               
4         Andrew                   Pfaff
```

I want to properly combine all part of a given name with ONLY a single
space between each name segment. Based on my research and implementation,
the best solution I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469665/replace-multi-spacing-in-strings-with-single-whitespace-python) - the one were `re` is used. Is this the  optimal way or is there
something better for this particular case?

My final approach was this:

```
df['full_name']=df[['First Name', 'Middle Name', 'Last Name']].apply(lambda x: re.sub(' +', ' ', ' '.join(x)), axis=1)
```

Comment: can't you just add them together `df['full_name']=df['First Name'] +' ' + df['Middle Name'] + ' ' + df['Last Name']`

Comment: @kenan that's not "ONLY a single space" if middle or last name are empty.

Comment: assuming names is a list of your columns `df[names].apply(lambda x : x.str.cat(sep=' '),axis=1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply join as:

```
df['full_name'] = df[['First Name','Middle Name', 'Last Name']].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
df['full_name'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['First Name'] + ' ' + row['Middle Name'] + ' ' + row['Last Name'], axis=1)
```